# Tightness of probability-measure

Tags: probability, measure-theory, random-variables

I would like to prove the following statement:

I have **$_$** a sequence of integrable random variables s.t $(_)→∞$,  as $→∞$.  Is it true or false that this implies that the laws $_$ of $_$  are not tight?

**My attempt:** Basically if I choose $n^2$ with probability $\frac{1}{n}$ and  $[0,1]$ with the rest probability.So which means **False**. I am I correct with this result ?

Comment: Your argument looks fine to me.

Comment: What does 'and $[0,1]$ with the rest probability' mean?

Comment: You are correct. Degenerated random variables are handsome here.